# How to map git log to json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, git

After run `git log --all --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --date=short --no-merges`, my git output looks like below:

```
84hf6f3 Some Author 2022-07-13 some commit message
```

the above output is in this order always `sha|author|date|commit message`.

And here i have a problem, how to map this output to json file, with fields like above?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of what you have already tried? At the moment, the question doesn't seem to know which language it wants. Are you using node?

Comment: look at tags, there is no without reason

Comment: Are you using a specific host like GitHub or does this need to work in any git repository?

Comment: with any repository

Comment: I'm not sure the tags help here. How do you expect JS to interact with git without using node?

Comment: so all these are single spaces between values?

Comment: @evolutionxbox with using `exec` imported from `child-process` I can using git inside node project

Comment: @Apostolos exactly

Comment: Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```bash
git log --all --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --date=short --no-merges | 
  jq -R '[ inputs | split("\t") | { hash: .[0], author: .[1], date: .[2], message: .[3] }]'
```

The `-R` (`--raw-input`) option tells `jq` that the input is not JSON. Instead, each line of the input is passed to the filter as string.

The `jq` script (filter) explained

```
[                     # wrap everything in a list (array)  <---------------------+
  inputs              # process the list of all inputs (a list of strings)       |
  | split("\t")       # each input is split into a list of pieces                |
  | {                 # for each list of pieces created above, create an object  |
      hash: .[0],     # put the first piece as `hash`                      ^     |
      author: .[1],   # the second piece as `author`                       |     |
      date: .[2],     # the third as `date`                                |     |
      message: .[3]   # and so on...                                       |     |
    }                 # this is where the object ends ---------------------+     |
]                     # remember the wrapper on the first line? it ends here ----+
```

The output looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "hash": "199a8e4a",
    "author": "me",
    "date": "2018-07-05",
    "message": "Implemented frobulator"
  },
  {
    "hash": "85e76d6e",
    "author": "Someone else",
    "date": "2018-07-03",
    "message": "Added a valuable contribution"
  },
  {
    "hash": "ba91c1dc",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "date": "2018-05-24",
    "message": "Initial Commit"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Node.js:

```
import { simpleGit } from 'simple-git';

simpleGit().log()
```

Comment: Nope, I want do it withour using 3rd party libs

Comment: But you're still using Node, right?

Comment: yes, more details is in main post and last comments

Comment: https://www.nushell.sh/cookbook/parsing_git_log.html